# Preload entire next page Ionic Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, caching, preload

**Situation:** I created a website where the user has to go through a series of pages in order. The images take a while to load in due to a slow internet connection.

**Question:** How can I preload all of the images on the next page (or the entire page) while the user is viewing the current page?

**Possible solution:** Is there a way I can load the next HTML page in the current page with a *hidden* attribute so that all of the images are cached beforehand?

**Research:** I have many pages and images. I looked into displaying a loader gif while the images load, but that requires JS. I couldn't find a way to detect when all images are successfully loaded without checking each individually.

**Preference:** I prefer the idea of the next page's content being cached while viewing the current.